Can you please define this yeshivish term?
I was listening to someone explaining a halachic question and they kept returning to a term I could not figure out the meaning of from context "shas of the hock" (likely misspelled). It seemed to be used that in this situation, due to differing details, the halacha does not follow what you would usually expect. I would like to know a better definition of the idiom, perhaps correcting my misimpression, what language(s) it comes from, and also if it is coded towards stringency, leniency, or neutral.

She’at ha-dechak, or in yeshivish pronunciation shas hadchak.
The Hebrew is שעת הדחק, literally a pressing time, or, more colloquially, under pressing circumstances, or in extremis.
This is a very common phrase in halachic discourse, usually in the context of employing a leniency that one would not use in normal circumstances. A google search will probably give you a good sense of how and when it is used.

"hour of pressure"

+1 for figuring out what was meant by “shas of the hock”

The term שעת דחק, means under pressing circumstances.
What one does under pressure, is not necessarily what one does in regular, day to day conditions.
Here is a link for a complete explanation: https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%93%D7%97%D7%A7

+1 for figuring out what was meant by “shas of the hock”

This linked article is very helpful.

A better  way to translate Shas HaDechak is emergency situation.

I'm not sure this is better. Emergency may imply risk of injury or death, which isn't necessarily what is going on here.

This is most certainly not what it means.

Welcome to MiYodeya Mike and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!
